# Storm kafkaSpout setup in 1.0.0 slower than 0.9.5

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I have setup for kafkaSpout with Storm 0.9.5 ,1.0.0,1.0.2.I am seeing record processing very slow in 1.0.0,1.0.2 than 0.9.5. To process 100000 tuple Strings it took 2 min with 0.9.5 and 10 min in 1.0.0,1.0.2.I am consuming the string from Kafka 0.9. topology —- kafkaSpout(1) -> bolt(1). Please su

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What could be the reason for this latency in storm 1.x integration with Kafka?Does any configuration change needed to improve the performence?